# Is there a way change hostname ip mapping for a process/thread temporarily using ruby or linux command?

Tags: ruby, linux, dns, hostname, hosts

Is there a way to set the hostname ip mapping temporarily for a process using ruby or some native linux command?

The objective is to make the process aware of the hostname and its ip. The rest of the processes should be unaware of this change.

I am aware that you can specify the hostname lookup in /etc/hosts or by creating a custom DNS server but the change affects all processes within the system.

Comment: Ugh, this sounds _very_ hacky and nasty. What's the high-level problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to automate localization testing where there are mulitple domains pointing to localhost ex: abc.com/en and abc.co.uk/en pointing to localhost, but the context is known to a process

Comment: [Several approaches documented over on Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts).